# Passing delegate as object property

Tags: vb.net

Using .net 3.5,I have a working form where I pass a delegate by constructor,like that:

```vb
Public Delegate Sub runDelegate(ByVal pId As String)
Private delgate As runDelegate

Public Sub New(ByVal dlg As runDelegate, ByVal pBtCaption As String)
    ' ...
    If dlg IsNot Nothing Then
        cbtRunOnSelected.Text = pBtCaption 
        cbtRunOnSelected.Visible = True
    End If
    delgate = dlg
End Sub

Private Sub cbtRunOnSelected_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles cbtRunOnSelected.Click
    delgate.Invoke(DirectCast(bs.Current, DataRowView)("id").ToString) 'call works
End Sub
```

but instead of passing multiple parameters I want to group all into one,an object(more flexibile if I want to add them in future),so I changed my code:

```vb
Public Class cDelegate
    Public Delegate Sub runDelegate(ByVal pId As String)
    Public btCaption As String
End Class

Private delgate As cDelegate
Public Sub New( ByVal dlg As cDelegate)
    ' ...
    If dlg IsNot Nothing Then
        cbtRunOnSelected.Text = dlg.btCaption
        cbtRunOnSelected.Visible = True
    End If

    delgate = dlg
End Sub
```

but the problem is here,that code dosn't work:

```vb
Private Sub cbtRunOnSelected_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles cbtRunOnSelected.Click
    delgate.runDelegate.Invoke(DirectCast(bs.Current, DataRowView)("id").ToString)
    'error here
End Sub
```

> Access of shared member, constant member, enum member or nested type through an instance; qualifying expression will not be evaluated.

Answer (score 1):

I hope this helps. I made a small example showing what you're missing. Specifically, that is a method which you will actually execute.

A delegate is a method design

A delegate instance is a method pointer

You need a delegate instance, which you are lacking. This example should help you see that

```vb
Public Class ClassName
    Public Delegate Sub DelegateName(pId As String)
    Public DelegateInstance As New DelegateName(AddressOf method)
    Private Sub method(pId As String)
        MessageBox.Show(pId)
    End Sub
End Class

Private instance As ClassName

Public Sub New(classInstance As ClassName)
    instance = classInstance
End Sub

Private Sub cbtRunOnSelected_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    instance.DelegateInstance.Invoke("string")
End Sub
```

I changed names because you named everything delegate and it was confusing.

Comment: for me DelegateInstance doens't work,I need to run outside code: Dim wF As New myForm( New myForm.cDelegate With {.btCaption = "Press",...})

Comment: @mrapi but where is the actual delegate instance being set? In my example, the instance is being set to run `method` when it is constructed. What do you actually do with that string? Where is that method?

Comment: @mrapi It *could* be in your code. i.e. `Dim wF As New myForm(New myForm.cDelegate With {.btCaption = "Press", .myDel = New runDelegate(AddressOf someMethodWhichTakesString)})`. Of course, you need to create the instance `myDel`, which would be equivalent to `DelegateInstance` in my answer.

Comment: @mrapi the code above works. You would need to make it work in your environment by changing some names. Have you tried that?

Comment: Hi.it works but not for my case: 'AddressOf method' ,I need 'method' to be changed,it can take different names,but not working for above example.finally I give up and return to my old working code